# Child contains an instance of the parent DTD/xml

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, lxml, dtd

I am currently learning about xml and DTD and I came across a DTD which was a bit puzzling .

```
<!ELEMENT foo (superpowers*)>
<!ELEMENT superpowers ( foo | agility )>
```

Firstly is this DTD legal ?

whenever I try to generate a corresponding xml file i get the following error,

> > Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 12, in 
> >         foo.append(superpowers)\n   File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 832, in lxml.etree._Element.append   File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line
> >     1283, in lxml.etree._appendChild ValueError: cannot append parent to
> >     itself

The code I am using for xml generation in python is represented by this pseudo code.

```
from lxml import etree as xml
import pprint

foo = xml.Element("foo")
superpowers = xml.Element("superpowers")

x = True

if x :
  foo = xml.Element("foo")
  superpowers.append(foo)
  foo.append(superpowers)

else :
  agility = xml.Element("agility")
  superpowers.append(agility)
  foo.append(superpowers)

tree = xml.ElementTree(foo)
print (xml.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True))

with open("foo.xml", "wb") as op:
  tree.write(op, pretty_print=True) #pretty_print used for indentation
```

Have I overlooked anything ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <!ELEMENT foo (superpowers*)>
> <!ELEMENT superpowers ( foo | agility )>
> ```
>
> Firstly is this DTD legal ?

Yes, that partial DTD is legal. (I say partial because there isn't an element declaration for `agility`.)

It's saying that `foo` can contain zero or more `superpowers` and `superpowers` must contain exactly one `foo` or `agility`.

For example, this would be valid according to that DTD...

```xml
<foo>
    <superpowers>
        <foo/>
    </superpowers>
    <superpowers>
        <foo>
            <superpowers>
                <foo/>
            </superpowers>
        </foo>
    </superpowers>
</foo>
```

The error you're getting makes sense; you can't `foo.append(superpowers)` because `superpowers` is already the parent of `foo`. (Like Harry Dunne says, "*You can't triple stamp a double stamp Lloyd!*".)

What you would need to do is create a brand new `foo` and append `superpowers` to that.

Example...

```py
if x :
  foo = xml.Element("foo")
  superpowers.append(foo)
  foo2 = xml.Element("foo")
  foo2.append(superpowers)
```

and what you'd end up with is (comments added to try to help clarify)...

```xml
<foo><!--foo2-->
    <superpowers>
        <foo><!--original foo--></foo>
    </superpowers>    
</foo>
```